# Save data in memory on LPC1768

Tags: c

I'm trying save data in memory on LPC1768. I want to load data when I put on the microcontroller. I expect data don't erase when I put off the machine.

I'm programming in C. I would need a example code in C but I fount a example code in C++ only: http://developer.mbed.org/users/okano/code/IAP/

Thanks everybody. Bye.

Comment: The C++ example you found is pretty straightforward.  Between that code and the chip's manual it shouldn't be too hard to come up with a C version of the routines.

Comment: Thanks. I'm going to try do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write data to the flash on the LPC1768 using the IAP commands documented in [the user manual](http://www.nxp.com/documents/user_manual/UM10360.pdf) in Chapter 32 "Flash memory interface and programming".  Specifically, section 32.8 documents the IAP (In Application Programming) commands that let the program running on the device write to flash.  Or you can write to the flash using the ISP (In-System Programming) serial port protocol documented starting in section 32.3.

You can use a tool like [Flash Magic](http://www.flashmagictool.com/) or [lpc21isp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/lpc21isp/) to program using the ISP protocol if you don't want to roll your own.

Comment: Thanks Michael Burr.